# Vue.js client Rails API delete object

Tags: vuejs2, jsonapi-rails

I have a rails 5.1 api delivering json which is being consumed by a Vue.js powered front-end. I can CRU but not Delete.  I have checked in Postman and the delete request works as expected, but for some reason it does not work via the Vue.js client.

I suspect the problem is in the link itself, but I am not sure how to make a delete request via the browser so I have not tested it there. Here is the code for the link:

```

```
in Entities.vue:

 <tr v-for="entity in entities" :key="entity.id">
      <td>{{ entity.title }}</td>
      <td>{{ entity.description }}</td>
      <td align="center">
        <router-link v-bind:to="{ name: 'EditEntity', params: { id: entity.id } }">Edit</router-link> |
        <a href="#" @click="deleteEntity(entity.id)">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

```

and the javascript for the action:

```
in src/services/EntitiesService.js

deleteEntity (id) {
  return Api().delete('entities/' + id)
}
```

and src/services/Api.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default() => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
  })
}
```

here is the network request which i can tell doesn't look right:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 24 Nov 2018 21:57:10 GMT
ETag: W/"144-+Koybw7A2IzbrCsGVT8Z3o3UXFk"
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: ahoy_visitor=7034198d-14a1-4d36-8bcf-495741e6c80a; _ga=GA1.1.491252661.1536002193; _blackops_session=eVpXOUVJNzB1QVI1OE4yVFowWEFDUmRVVXNyTG9FUE9Da2N6RmpsTDVEVmpEOVpDUkUyNTRJeFIwWXB5UU01T2FoYzBBd1NSbnRkdlBOT3BWL1NadG91d0labWcxZmQ3dGIzRkZ6QVlIcURsM0JxS1hERGpndDducnJIMEROYzhGeXlMc2NmSFdVclRrZktqdk02WkU4YmRQdnpvTWlFY3lRQnhBSVJZWTRSOWkybHFtV3JEemtHYTZtZUVrQmVxZkNrc25lK0doQm44VFR4c1RKaHNsUT09LS0zWmZaNWIyZEdDZlRJMWprcmFqNUlBPT0%3D--cd8059919655e6544a22a47b3d93785928644e8c; _book_review_session=Rsqk%2FCrHd8tvmx1vP4l%2B3QltWUP%2BVyE%2BkrPAUWMW%2BbbqOusZORm8vCJ2mlvzTK4aASYVZhSM9bMBGY%2BjDde0WEk7hMryeUagAK0%2FTE%2BlQcsXRVJCVRI39E42Ib4uh%2BXA9bBFk%2B4FeZveolx5njVNedtDgv3C0Y8Lud%2FxkvJYxWl%2FSCkU0eGr1fRheaynCF0fxftsScwQyuTscuhNDoSFC%2BrMgqS0Q%2B1bnl2p--IiFoc%2BJv6jQnURmH--h5yYqRKwplqk%2BY0Eyb7edQ%3D%3D; _jadenseffort_session=4QnEiv%2FhvJQuhUfFF%2BYt5e9tbNnKtzLqkJQ1pGhQ56bbKfkPfY7qP937u2PL0l4T14vfyRNj2m3tP%2FVk1ZQH%2B0yMOV%2Fmbe0KTtvXzCQrqA0PGRqHV9fPwzgZKCpPJit%2FndfXbOMi%2BS6FhSWYKd8%3D--w8URgVaBAILD6N7M--paJNx6RiLH5UN5J0MX7Wng%3D%3D
Host: localhost:8080
If-None-Match: W/"144-+Koybw7A2IzbrCsGVT8Z3o3UXFk"
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Could you please post what your network request is?  Side question, what is the reason for using form requests through axios over json?

Comment: I thought axios was required since the requests are being made to a remote server separate from the client. I was following various tutorials

Comment: You will have a much easier time on API requests if you use `json` as the request instead of form encoded.  Axios is a good client for that.

Comment: Side note, that request is to port 8080 and is a get request to some express server.  What you need is the request to port 3000

Comment: port 8080 is where the client app is being served. looks like it is retrieving the Vue favicon only, unrelated to the attempt to delete except that on clicking to Delete, the page is refreshing. Api.js combined with EntitiesService.js is aimed at sending a DELETE request to localhost:3000/entities/:id, but it's not happening onclick.